# Rename Folders in Outlook PST-File 

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2007, outlook-2010, pst

since a few days I'm trying to rename the sent mail folder, deleted elements and the inbox folder via c#.

I've tryed something like this:

```
 List<Outlook.MailItem> mailItems = new List<Outlook.MailItem>();
            Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.NameSpace outlookNs = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            // Add PST file (Outlook Data File) to Default Profile
            outlookNs.AddStore(pstFilePath);
            Outlook.MAPIFolder rootFolder = outlookNs.Stores[pstName].GetRootFolder();

           Outlook.Folders subFolders = rootFolder.Folders;

  foreach (Outlook.Folder folder in subFolders)
            {

              folder.Name =  (folder.Name == "deleted Elements"?"deleted":folder.Name);
}
```

But without success. I always get the exceptiion that I do not have permissions to change the name. Other custom created folders I'm able to rename without any problems.

Is there something to do to unlock the folder?
Or is there an other possibility to access the folders?

Thanks a lot

Edit: The Expetion is: You do not have permissions.

Comment: Please provide the documentation for the exception in question.  Your boolean assigned statement makes very little sense.

Comment: I'm looking for the same options in Outlook 2010 but no luck at all. Apparently there is no option for this. As far I understood the older version of outlook supported such renaming of the default folders. I would welcome any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

```
public string RenameFolder(string name, string folderid)
    {
        Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.NameSpace ns = null;
        Outlook.Folder folder = null;
        string n= null;

        try
        {
            ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            folder = ns.GetFolderFromID(folderid) as Outlook.Folder;
            n=folder.Name;
            folder.Name = (folder.Name = name) ;
            return n + " has been successfully changed to " + folder.Name;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (app != null)
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(app);
            }

            if (folder != null)
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(folder);
            }

            if (ns != null)
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ns);
            }
        }
    }
```

this code is working for me..when i run visual studio in administator mode..

Comment: Could you please explain the necessity of double folder renaming?

`folder.Name = (folder.Name = name) ;`